# Flatten Feed logic in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with the below data,

```
id  cd_used
1   trl
1   upf
2   upf
3   trl
3   trl
```

I have to apply flatten feed logic and derive the below output.

```
id  cd_used
1   trlupf
2   upfonly
3   trlonly
```

One of the method was filter the table using cd_used and for for two subqueries, and the result of intersect can be added to trlupf, any other methods for implementing this?

Comment: For id=1 rows, why `1   trlupf`   and not `1   upftrl`? What determines ordering of cd_used ?

Comment: it is not based on any order, a default value, consider 'trlupf' or even u can print 'both' as the output, if an id has both the codes. I just want to categorize the ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH tab_temp
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS id, 'upf' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS id, 'upf' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL)
  SELECT t.id,
         LISTAGG (t.cd_used, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.cd_used DESC)
            "cd_used"
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                 id,
                 CASE
                    WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT cd_used) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 1
                    THEN
                       cd_used || 'Only'
                    ELSE
                       cd_used
                 END
                    cd_used
            FROM tab_temp) t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tab_temp
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 AS id, 'upf' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 AS id, 'upf' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 AS id, 'trl' AS cd_used FROM DUAL)
,  aggage as
(
select id, listagg (cd_used) within group (order by cd_used) as new_cd
from (select distinct id, cd_used from tab_temp)
group by id
)
select id, case 
             when new_cd in (select cd_used from tab_temp) then new_cd||'only'
             else new_cd
           end as cd_used
from aggage
```